# TPanel cleaning (Lazarus)

Tags: pascal, lazarus

Tell me,please,whether `TPanel` has method by which you can clear all the objects on the `TPanel`?

For example, if some labels were placed on `TPanel`(Label.Visible = true), then after applying the method they became invisible (Label.Visible: = false).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want to destroy all objects on the TPanel or you need only hide?

If you need only hide all components of the panel this codes may help you:

[Example of HideAll components of panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8kyb.png)

```
procedure TForm1.chk_Visible_AllChange(Sender: TObject);
var
  n: Integer;
  cmp : TComponent;
begin

  for n:= 0 to ComponentCount-1 do
    begin
      cmp := Components[n];
      if cmp.GetParentComponent=Panel1 then
        begin
          if cmp is TLabel then
            TLabel(cmp).Visible:= chk_Visible_All.Checked;
          if cmp is TButton then
            TButton(cmp).Visible:= chk_Visible_All.Checked;
          if cmp is TMemo then
            TMemo(cmp).Visible:= chk_Visible_All.Checked;
          if cmp is TGroupBox then
            TGroupBox(cmp).Visible:= chk_Visible_All.Checked;
        end;
    end;
end;
```

Comment: Thank you, that's what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

Of course You can use

```
Panel.Visible = false;
```

All elements which have Your panel as parent would change visibility.

If You create controls at runtime You should assign them the right parent with

```
myLabel.Parent = Panel;
```